# ReCaptcha v3 stalling out in Safari(Mac and IOS)

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, polymer-2.x

I've stuck ReCaptcha 3 in a polymer 2 app and it works great, except that in Safari, when I try to get the token, the call to grecaptcha.execute stalls. Every. Single. Time.

I've tried implementing different ways, sticking all captcha stuff straight in the index to keep it all out of the shadow dom, wrapping everything up in a component, automatically rendering vs explicit. It just doesn't work in Safari.

Also, probably doesn't mean much, but in my testing, some devices consistently just lock up the browser and never move on, while others will always un-freeze after a few minutes.

I've also seen similar behavior on our sites using the v2 invisible ReCaptcha, except that with that one iOS Safari crashes on all devices and Mac doesn't have any issue.